# Mypy allowing `List[str]` to have values of type `Tuple[str, List[str]]`

Tags: python, mypy

The following minified example was originally found while making changes to my work's code base. I have the line `x: List[str] = []` so I expect that mypy will enforce that, but in this example it seems it does not. If I want mypy to catch this, what should I do differently?

```
from typing import List

x: List[str] = []
y = ["world"]
z = ["hello"]

def go(boop):
    return f"{boop}!", y

x = list(map(go, z))
print(x)

# output:
# [('hello!', ['world'])]
```

```
$ mypy mypy_lists.py   
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

```
$ python3 mypy_lists.py
[('hello!', ['world'])]
```

EDIT:

For context, the `, y` part of the definition of `go` was a copy-paste error, and I expected to be protected against that by just the `x: List[str]` annotation, but maybe I have to update my internal model of mypy type checking, and just trust it less.

EDIT 2:

Given the accepted answer, the amount I can trust mypy with type hints seems to be directly related to the way mypy is configured. Not terribly surprising, but a good thing to remember.

Comment: Isn't it because you reassign x, so mypy consider it as a new variable with a different type than the original x ? If instead of `x = list(map(go, z))` you do `x.extends(list(map(go, z)))` does mypy complains ?

Comment: Add type hints for `go` and recheck

Comment: @LouisSaglio mypy will typically complain if an assignment would change the type of a variable.

Comment: You can also use the `--strict` flag which avoids issues like this.

Comment: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code

Comment: @LouisSaglio, `x.extend` seems to still pass mypy checks too.

Comment: Thanks, @Axe319! I think `--strict` is the answer I was looking for since "be more diligent about type annotations" was not. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `mypy` ignores [untyped function definitions](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code).

This helps gradually introduce type annotations into an existing codebase without having to add them all at once.

Personally for new projects I run `mypy` with the [`--strict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html?highlight=strict#cmdoption-mypy-strict) option to avoid accidentally leaving functions unannotated and bypassing type checks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that adding type annotations to the `go` function causes mypy to correctly pick up on the problem:

```
$ mypy -c 'from typing import List, Tuple

x: List[str] = []
y = ["world"]
z = ["hello"]

def go(boop: str) -> Tuple[str, List[str]]:
    return f"{boop}!", y

x = list(map(go, z))
print(x)'
<string>:10: error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[Any], Tuple[str, List[str]]]"; expected "Callable[[str], str]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. It looks like it still catches it if I annotate it with `-> str`. For context `, y` was a copy-paste error. I'll update the question with this too.